# Is there any dual sim phone which can use both cards at once? If yes, could someone recommend me such phone?

Tags: smartphones, mobile-phone

I have 2 sim cards. One provides me internet, another provides calling and SMS.

I can't use internet while someone is calling me. Are there any phones on which I can use internet when someone is calling me?

Could someone recommend me such phone? Other prefered features:

- Removable battery;
- water resistant;
- military complaint (like MIL-STD-810G compliant);
- not less than 32gb storage;
- not less than 3 gb of ram;
- available bootloader unlocking;
- root;
- Xposed framework;
- OTG support;
- 4G, 5G but as I know there are no 5G phones with removable battery;
- IPS or PLS LCD screen, not less than 4,5 inch;
- processor not less than 1,4 Ghz quad;
- Camera not less than 14 MP unless it has exclusively good camera;
- More than dual sim is also fine;
- SD card support not less than 64GB;
- FM radio;
- IR blaster.

Most important features:

- Removable battery
- not less than 16GB storage
- root
- bootloader unlocking
- xposed framework
- otg support
- 4G
- SD card dedicated slot not less than 64GB
- LCD IPS or PLS
- not less than 2 GB of ram
- processor not less than 1,4 Ghz quad
- Camera not less than 14 MP unless it has exclusively good camera
- Screen not less than 4,5 inch

Comment: They're usually called "Active Dual-SIM" phones. I will try to find a few models and write an answer but is there any other specific features you need? (Size, storage, camera, Android version, etc.)

Comment: You literally said everything except the price range. And that's a lot of requirements.

Comment: I don't expect you to find a phone with all these features, but you can take a look to "Most important features" (edited).

Comment: I can't even find a phone which has removable battery and active dual sim lol.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding a phone that meets all of your requirements, maybe you should just use two phones? The technical reason for not being able to use both SIM cards at the same time is because there is only one modem in the phone. If you are on a call, the data can only come in on the SIM being used for that call because that one takes priority over the modem. If you find it acceptable to use data on the other SIM *only during calls*, you may be able to use a normal dual SIM phone with a software fix/change that automatically switches data to the calling SIM.

Comment: Do you know any good lists of these phones? It's hard to find for me.